# Equals method for objects

Tags: java, object, equals

I'm trying to write an equals method for objects that compares their fields and return true if they're equal.

```
private int x, y, direction;
private Color color;

public boolean equals(Ghost other){
   if (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y &&
       this.direction == other.direction && this.color == other.color)
      return true;
   else 
      return false;
}
```

What could be wrong with this?

Comment: @fprime: You only need one return statement, and no `if`. ;-)

Comment: print out the result of the individual if phrases (eg `this.x == other.x`) before the if statement.  See which one(s) fails.

Comment: Are any of the variables being compared Object types, as opposed to primitive types?

Comment: Now wait, does what I'm doing compare memory addresses or actual values?

Comment: It will compare the values, have you ran your code to see if it works?

Comment: @frime - it depends on x, y, direction and color being value types or reference types.

Comment: Value types will be compared by value, reference types (objects) will be compared by the reference (address).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `color` [appears to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939274/java-initializing-objects) a [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), that's a class, and therefore a reference type, which means you need to use `equals()` to compare the colors.

```
if (/* ... && */ this.color.equals(other.color)) {
```

As noted in the comments, using `==` to compare reference types is really comparing memory addresses in Java. It'll only return `true` if they both refer to the same object in memory.

---

[akf points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950439/equals-method-for-objects/3950483#3950483) that you need to use the base `Object` class for your parameter, otherwise you're not overriding `Object.equals()`, but actually overloading it, i.e. providing a different way of calling the same-named method. If you happen to pass an object of a totally different class by accident, unexpected behavior might occur (although then again if they are of different classes it will return `false` correctly anyway).

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Ghost))
        return false;

    // Cast Object to Ghost so the comparison below will work
    Ghost other = (Ghost) obj;

    return this.x == other.x
        && this.y == other.y
        && this.direction == other.direction
        && this.color.equals(other.color);
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok got it. I already had an equals method created so I just used it on the color field and now it works:) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In principle, this looks fine.

Note however that you are comparing using `==`. For primitives, this is no problem, but for objects it will check for the same instance, not the same value. This may or may not be what you want. If you are comparing e.g. java.lang.Strings, you'd want to use `equals` instead (and check for `null`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are comparing object variables instead of primitive types, you should be using a `this.color.equals(other.color)` comparison instead.

In your case, it also depends on how you created the Color objects.  if you used the static instances (such as Color.BLUE), then actually, it shouldn't matter.  If you created the Color object from rgb values, it definitely matters.  Either way, it is best to get used to using .equals() for object variables.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider is that you are not overriding the `equals` method from `Object`, as you are changing the param type.  You might find this method will not be used in all cases as you might expect.  Instead of:

```
public boolean equals(Ghost other){
```

you should have:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
```

and then internally test whether the `other` param is an `instanceof` `Ghost` and cast as necessry.

Comment: +1 Nice catch there. Shall I fix my answer, since as it stands my answer's second part is incorrect?

Comment: yeah, add it for a more complete answer.