# how to compare two objects/references in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equals method for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950439/equals-method-for-objects)

i have below code.

```
public class SomeClass{ 
OtherClass clas = new OtherClass();  
OtherClass some; 
some=this; 
if(some != this) {
    s.y.s.o("true");
}
```

my question is which one is correct?
 some != this or some.equals(this) ?

Comment: `System.out.println(some != this);`
`System.out.println(some.equals(this));`
See what you get :)

Comment: You would get a few compilation for starters.  `SomeClass` doesn't extend `OtherClass` so this example isn't even valid.  And there's also the red herrings (what is the purpose of `clas` in this example?)  Please put more effort into the content of your question.

Answer (score 22):

To compare object references, you use `==` and `!=`, while `equals` is used to compare the values.

Answer (score 10):

What do you want to compare?

`==` compares to see if the two references are to the EXACT SAME OBJECT.

`equals` compares to see if the two references are to objects which have matching properties, based on the class-specific criteria in the class's `equals` implementation.

Comment: Note that the default implementation of the equals method (as defined in the Java.lang.Object class) is to compare the object references. So be sure to override the equals method in your object otherwise it will have the same behavior ass the == operator.

Answer (score 8):

You use `operator!=` or `operator==` when you want to check for **identity** of two objects [if they are actually the same object]

You use `equals()` when you want to check for **equality**. [if two object are equal, as the `equals()` method defined them].

It is hard to know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but *usually* when comparing two reference objects, we want to use `equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java `==` compares references (i.e. addresses)  while `equals` compares object equality (and you can override it to compare based the member variables you see fit)

In your post you compare to see if `some` is the same object as `this`. Is this what you want to do? If yes then the `some!=this` is correct (and is `false` since `some` refers to `this`)

Comment: hi thanx for ur answer. My requirement is are both some and this refers rerers the same object? In this case some!=this and some.equals(this) gives same result?

Comment: @user1199334:Since you do `some=this` then yes `some` and `this` refer to the same object.If both refer to the same object you understand of course that `some.equals(this)` must be `true` since you are comparing something to itself...And `some!=this` can only be `false` since you have already assigned `some` to refer to `this`.What is this?Homework?

Answer (score 2):

== compares the references. That is, are these two objects located at the same place.
.Equals compares the things pointed to by those references. That is, are these two objects equivalent.