# Why are these lines part of the Java Development Kit?

Tags: java, equals, abstractset

People are confused about my question. So let's reformulate. Why would a developer use this first two lines from the AbstractSet? Why would I ever want to compare if object.equals(object)? If they share the same reference, aren't them equal already? In what circumstance a programmer would want that check? The only one I can think of is the one you are getting an object that you don't know where is it coming from, and by not knowing the origin, you perform a fast check to see if they are the same. Is this assumption correct?

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{ 
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) o;

    if (c.size() != size())
        return false;

    return containsAll(c);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: `this == this` ... the object is equal to itself, why would it be false?

Comment: It is performed by comparing `this` to `o` with the `==` operator, and returning `true` if they match.

Comment: It is just a short cut to avoid comparing every elements inside the `List`, if the passing in `o` is with the same reference as `this`, i.e., you are calling `equals` with the same object instance.

Comment: Why you're using `AbstractSet.equals()` for a SkipList is the only mystery here.

Comment: How dare you question my weird choices, @EJP?! It actually isn't *the* equals method from the AbstractSet, since the inners (aka size and containsAll) aren't the same because I overrided them with my beautiful log n contains method. I just wanted a starting point and discovered that List actually calls the method from there.

Comment: "Why would I ever want to compare if object.equals(object)? If they share the same reference, aren't them equal already?" Well yes, they are. But the caller may not know that. This is an optimization. It's an extremely common optimization in `equals` implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals method not only needs to be correct, but also *fast*. Furthermore, it does not know anything about the incoming object and cannot make any assumptions. A very fast check is reference comparing. If they have the same reference, you can give a very quick answer without iterating over sets.

Answer (score 0):

if object reference in memory address is equal to `this`, it return true.

```
if (o == this)
        return true;
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950439/equals-method-for-objects) post